# Database Modeling with multiple many-to-many relations in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many, django-signals

I could need some help on designing my models and their relationships.

## Short overview

- **Book**: book titles *(e.g. "Lord of the Rings")*
- **Tag**: tags associated with books *(e.g. "Fantasy", "Wizard", "Epic fight")*
- **Aspect**: aspects associated with tags, or, in other words, things users can rate when a specific tag occurs, e.g.:

  - *for the tag "Fantasy" aspects could be "World Detail" and "Time"*
  - *for the tag "Epic fight" aspects could be "Gore Level" and "Fight tension"*

Each Tag can be used in multiple instances of Book *(e.g. "Lord of the Rings" and "Discworld" both have the tag "Fantasy")*.

Each Aspect can be used in multiple instances of Tag *(e.g. "Fantasy" and "Scifi" both have the aspect "World Detail")*.

Here is a descriptive image:

[image]

(wow, these are big ones)

### "Why do you need that extra table BookAspect?" you might ask?

**Because i want to store user ratings for each aspect that is related to a specific book.**

That's the main problem here. I want to model this in Django and this is what i got so far:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    tags = ManyToManyField(Tag)
    # the following line is a workaround...
    aspects = models.ManyToManyField(Aspect, through='BookAspect')

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    aspects = models.ManyToManyField(Aspect)

class Aspect(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

# this class is a workaround ...
class BookAspect(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    aspect = models.ForeignKey(Aspect)
    # this is from django-ratings
    rating = RatingField(range=5, can_change_vote=True, allow_delete=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('book', 'aspect',)
```

In addition to the models, i created a `m2m_changed` signal listener for `action="post_add"`:

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Book.tags.through)
def m2m_changed_book(sender, instance, action, reverse, pk_set, **kwargs):
    if action is not 'post_add' or reverse:
        return

    # iterate through all newly created tags to manually add
    # the aspects from each tag to the BookAspect table
    for tag_id in pk_set:
        aspects = Tag.objects.get(pk=tag_id).aspects.all()
        # this is annoying, i have to manually set the relations...
        for aspect in aspects:
            bookAspect = BookAspect(book=instance, aspect=aspect)
            bookAspect.save()
```

Although that should work, i would need additional logic to deal with removed tags.

But the real annoying thing is that i have to manually add the per-book-aspect-relations so that i can store user ratings. Naturally i need different ratings for the same aspect of different books.

## Questions

### 1. Is this the right way to do it, am i missing something or isn't it that complicated as i think?

### 2. Is it possible to "automate" the Book-Aspect relation so that i don't have to manually update the relations?

### 3. How can i model it in Django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I think it can be done with more simplicity.
- I think, to some extent.
- I would change:

  ```
  class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    tags = ManyToManyField(Tag)
  ```

Since the `aspects` field has nothing to do in the `Book` class.

I have no idea of why you wrote `BookAspect`. About user ratings, you can do:

```
class BookRating(models.Model):
  book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
  aspect = models.ForeignKey(Aspect)
  rating = models.RatingField()
  # Method to rate a book and check the aspect belong to one of the book's tags
  def rate(book, aspect):
    # check the aspect is related to a tag which is also related to the book
    # if so, save a new rating entry
  # You can also override the save() method to check the aspect is valid for the book
```

Comment: that's promising. but there is still the problem that i have to manually manage the contents of `BookRating` instead of getting the associations automatically since they are defined already somewhere else